# Subversion automatically create branch on trunk checkout

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have the following question,

I know its possible to prevent multiple users working from trunk in SVN however is it possible to create a branch automatically and switch to the created branch when a user checks out from trunk using tortoisesvn?

This is to try and stop multiple users working on trunk.

Thank you

Comment: No matter how much you can do with tools, starting with training/process/procedure to make everyone *understand* what and why they should be working a certain way should be your first step.

Comment: I would say you really, really don't want this. Does nobody need read-only access to trunk, to build or something? After they're done on their branch, how would they merge back to trunk, without a trunk checkout? How would they commit their merge to the trunk? Plus, what exactly is wrong with multiple users working on trunk?

Comment: Thanks, Ideally I would like to simply allow users to check in and out of trunk and merge back when they want too. I would just like that a branch is created by default so that when multiple users are working on a project they are not all pointing to trunk by accident.